# Issue in understanding jre directory structure

Tags: java, java-7

I installed **JDK 1.7 u 51 32 bit** on Windows 7 32 bit and **JDK 1.7 u 51 64 bit** on Windows 7 64 bit machine from following link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

Windows x86 (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-windows-i586.exe) 
Windows x64 (http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u51-b13/jdk-7u51-windows-x64.exe)

After installation I found different folder hierarchy creation in **jre**. I was surprised because it creates different structure without giving any option.

### Difference

JDK 1.7 u 51 32 bit is having three directories: -

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\client
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\dtplugin
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\plugin2
**Note: - There is no server directory**
 
While in JDK 1.7 u 51 64 bit is having different directory structure

C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\dtplugin
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\plugin2
**Note: - There is no client directory**

Now question comes here, because of what option JDk kit has created "client" and "server" directories.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are checking in the JRE folder to see this difference.

From [Java Hotspot VM FAQs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_download)

> For 32-bit Windows, if you download the JRE, you get only the client,
> you'll need to download the SDK to get both systems.
>
> For 64-bit, only the server system is included.

Check in the `java\jdk{version}\jre\bin` folder instead of `java\jre\bin` folder

Comment: Thanks Ajay, kindly help us to understand if 64 system include ony server system. Then why it is pointing client dir jvm.dll in registry (Kindly refer following thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318204/no-client-in-c-program-files-java-jre7-bin-in-jdk-7u51-windows-x64)

Comment: 64 bit should only have server. Can you uninstall both JDKs and separate JRE installations and try again.

Answer (score 1):

JIT Compiler

**Where do I get the server and client systems?**

Client and server systems are both downloaded with the 32-bit Solaris and Linux downloads. For 32-bit Windows, if you download the JRE, you get only the client, you'll need to download the SDK to get both systems.

For 64-bit, only the server system is included. On Solaris, the 64-bit JRE is an overlay on top of the 32-bit distribution. However, on Linux and Windows, it's a completely separate distribution.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html#compiler_download